# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeClass' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I dynamically created a jquery mobile checkbox group. and wanna binding event to enable select all function. Once executed, the chrome console indicates "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeClass' of undefined".here is the js code:

```
var arr=['<fieldset id="countryContainer" name="countryContainer" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">'];

arr.push('<input type="checkbox" id="country_all" name="country_all" value="all" /><label for="country_all">ALL</label>');      
for(var i=0;i<9;i++){
arr.push('<input type="checkbox" id="country_'+i+'" name="fe" value="'+i+'" /><label for="country_'+i+'">'+i+'</label>');       
}

arr.push('</fieldset>');

$('[name=cell1]').append(arr.join(''));

$.mobile.pageContainer.trigger("create");


var chkall=$('[name=country_all]');
chkall.on('change', function() {
var checked=(chkall.prop('checked')=="checked")? true:false;
$("#countryContainer").prop('checked',true).checkboxradio().checkboxradio("refresh"); //something goes wrong here.
});
```

And the html:

<table>
   <tr>
        <td id="j_9" name="cell1" class="mobilegridcell1" colspan="1" rowspan="1"></td>
   </tr>
 </table>

The thing is that I wanna select all of the checkboxes in the countryContainer by selecting the country_all checkbox. Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you calling `removeClass`?

Comment: your code above doesnt seem to have removeClass..

Comment: Just a note: You could do the check for checked like `chkall.is(':checked') ? true : false` or `chkall[0].checked` And if you probably should using `prop()` instead of `attr()` for checked.

Comment: @FelixKling Most likely it is the Mobile Framework when it is updating the widget.

Comment: This looks strange: `$('body').on('change', chkall, ...`. `chkall` appears to be a jQuery object, but the `on` function is supposed to take a selector there. Maybe try `$('body').on('change', '[name=country_all], ...`.

Comment: change this `$("#countryContainer").attr('checked',true).checkboxradio().checkboxradio("refresh");` to this `$("#countryContainer").prop('checked',true).checkboxradio("refresh");` jQM changes classes on calling `refresh`.

Comment: Hold on, you are calling `.checkboxradio('refresh')` on fieldset which is wrong. you should call it on checkbox / radio. Pls post your rendered html or post your code on jsfiddle. and binding `change` to `body` isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Omar: I pasted the html file and also do change as suggested above. Still has problems

Comment: $("#countryContainer").prop('checked',true).checkboxradio().checkboxradio("refresh"); First call checkbox without argument to initialize it then call it again with refresh argument to style it

Comment: @Gajotres As you suggested, the solution still has problem.

Comment: Because `#countryContainer` is fieldset it's not a checkbox. `$('#countrycontainer').find('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');` try it

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I misplaced the .checkboxradio('refresh') on the fieldset. Thanks to @Omar.